# ¿Cómo corregir un error al seleccionar registros de la base de datos?

Tags: php

Estoy realizando una lista en android studio ya que quiero traer todos los datos de la tabla llamado *t_vivres*, pero al momento de realizar pruebas de conexión me sale el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in

Cuando realizo el *echo* para visualizar es cuando me sale el error ya mencionado, ¿Cómo puedo resolver ese detalle?.

**conexion.php**

```
$host  = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$clave = "";
$database= "logishuman";

$mysql =  new mysqli($host,$user,$clave,$database);
$mysql -> set_charset("utf8");


if ($mysql->connect_error) {
die("Fallo la conexión" . $mysql->connect_error);
}else {

}
?>
```

**listViveres.php**

```
<?php 
 include('conexion.php');
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_viveres";
 $result = $mysqli_query ($mysql, $sql);
 $viveres = array();


if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$index['codigoViveres'] = $row['codigoViveres'];
$index['descriProducto'] = $row['descriPoducto'];
$index['tipoClasificacion'] = $row['tipoClasificacion'];
$index['cantidad'] = $row['cantidad'];
$index['unidadMedida'] = $row['unidadMedida'];
$index['fechaRegistro'] = $row['fechaRegistro'];
$index['fechaCaducidad'] = $row['fechaCaducidad'];
array_push($viveres,$index);
}
echo json_encode($viveres);
?>
```

Comment: Esto: `$mysqli_query` no lleva símbolo de `$`, simplemente debe ser: `mysqli_query(........................)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error ocurre porque estás usando `$` para llamar a una función de PHP. Ten en cuenta que `$` se usa para las variables y referencias de objetos, no para las funciones.

Aparte de eso, deberías evitar la mezcla de estilos, la cual se considera una mala práctica. Si en la conexión usas el estilo orientado a objetos, usa ese mismo estilo en todas las partes del código (de hecho, es posible que éste sea el origen de tu confusión aquí). Además, el estilo orientado a objetos es más claro, más breve y más moderno.

Luego, la forma en que lees los resultados no es correcta. Ten en cuenta que mysqli devuelve un recurso con los datos, luego, tendrías que mover ese recurso aplicando un método adecuado de lectura para ir sacando cada fila. Generalmente esto se hace dentro de un bucle `while` como podrás ver en los [ejemplos del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). Si no mueves en un bucle no obtendrás todas las filas.

También, considera simplificar el llenado del array que realizas en la parte del `while` (si las columnas no se llaman como las claves que te interesan puedes declarar alias para las mismas, y si hay columnas que no te interesan, escribe un `SELECT` explícito únicamente con las columnas que te interesen).

Aplicando todo lo dicho el código quedaría así:

```
<?php 
 include('conexion.php');
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_viveres";
 $result = $mysql->query($sql);
 $viveres = array();
 while ( $row=$result->fetch_assoc() ) {
     #No hace falta indicar uno a uno los elementos
     $viveres[]=$row;
 }
 echo json_encode($viveres);
?>
```

Comment: Ohh si es verdad no me percate de eso $, gracias A. Cedano

Comment: @Miguel de nada. Puedes votar también la respuesta positivamente marcando la flecha que apunta hacia arriba como forma de agradecimiento. Un saludo.